# Text is overflowing in IE when border radius applied to list

Tags: javascript, css

When border radius applied to list then the text is overflowing. This is happening only in IE. I am using IE11.

[image]

Comment: no code no help

Comment: Please show your CSS so that we can help you figure this out.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add padding to the content so as to prevent the text from cutting

```
padding: 15px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36raavxe/19/

Answer (score 0):

Please use `padding` , That will solve the issue